# how to handle arbitrary dimensional vector in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to create a function that can handle arbitrary dimensional vector, function in psudocode:

```
template<class T>
void printVector(vector<T> t){
    if(T==vector){
        printf("[");
        for(auto it=t.begin(),it!=t.end();++it){
            printVector(*it);
        }
        printf("]");
    }else{
        printf("%d ",t);
    }
}
```

for example:

```
vector<int> a;
a.push_back(12);
a.push_back(34);

printVector(a);
```

the output should be [12 34],

```
vector<vector<int> > b;
vector<int> b1;
b1.push_back(1);
b1.push_back(2);
b.push_back(b1);

vector<int> b2;
b2.push_back(3);
b2.push_back(4);
b.push_back(b2);

printVector(b);
```

the output should be [[1 2][3 4]]

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: What do you mean by "arbitrary dimensional vector"? If `std::vector` is representing a mathematical vector, the number of dimensions is equal to `size()`. You seem to want multidimensional arrays, which are more like matrices or tensors. The next question is whether the structure is more like a matrix, with equally-sized rows, or a tree, with a sequence of heterogeneous entries.

Comment: I think you can manage to get something done with recursion, the function accepts a `vector<T>` where `T` is already a `vector<vector<...>`

Comment: By the way, your vector initialization could be `vector<vector<int>> b{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C++ template system supports recursion. You had the right idea, but you need to overload the function:

```
void printVector(int t) {
    printf("%d ", t);
}

template<class T>
void printVector(std::vector<T> t) {
    printf("[");
    for(auto v : t){
        printVector(v);
    }
    printf("]");
}
```

The first function handles the base case. The recursive case is handled by the second function, and it should be easy to understand.

For your second example, the one that outputs `[[1 2 ][3 4 ]]`, the compiler ends up generating `printVector<vector<vector<int> > >()`, `printVector<vector<int> >()`, and it uses the leaf `printVector(int)`.

Of course you should give this function a better name.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question is marked as C++, why no take a C++ approach?

```
template <template <typename ...> class CONTAINER, typename ... ARGS>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const CONTAINER<ARGS ...> &container)
{
    o << '[';
    for (const auto &item : container)
    {
        o << item << ' ';
    }
    o << ']';

    return o;
}
```

This operator will handle any template and try to pass it to the `ostream::operator <<`, so it could be valid for any kind of container which contained type is supported by the `ostream::operator <<`.

If we define also a free `ostream::operator <<` to handle `std::pairs` it can be used also for `std::map`:

```
template <typename F, typename S>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const std::pair<F, S> &pair)
{
    return o << pair.first << ':' << pair.second;
}
```

<kbd>[I've tried it](http://ideone.com/sRNzzK)</kbd> with `std::vector<int>`, `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>` and the same for `std::valarray` and `std::set`; also with a `std::map`.

Beware! is ambiguous used with `std::string`! So it shouldn't be used in a scope where strings are printed or we should look for a way to disable the template for `std::string`.

---

#### Edit

The function approach suggested by [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29813673/499359) is also applicable to my approach and it doesn't collide with the `std::string` printing of `std::ostream`:

```
template <typename T>
void printContainer(const T &value)
{
    std::cout << value;
}

template <template <typename ...> class CONTAINER, typename ... ARGS>
void printContainer(const CONTAINER<ARGS ...> &container)
{
    std::cout << '[';
    for (const auto &item : container)
    {
        printContainer(item);
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << ']';
}
```